# How to make Message app search for phone number, not just email

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-2, sms

Even if I have the correct information on a person in the contact app, I am unable to make the "To field" in the message app find me the phone number (the auto-suggest feature). All it does is display the email information. If I click that, the message is converted to an mms-email. For instance; if i start typing out the name of a person, it will only suggest the email for that person even if that person is in the Contact list **with** a phone number.

So my question is: How can i make the SMS app find me the contacts phone number from my contact list? Or put differently:  Why is not the phonenumber displayed in the suggestion list just the email (even if its the SMS client)?

Background info:

- I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 with Ice Cream Sandwich (4.03)
- I tried the "Merge Contacts" option in the message app
- If i manualy type in the number it will be correctly linked to the ongoing thread with this person.